# How should I stop and analyze requests before blocking them in webRequest.OnBeforeRequest?

Tags: javascript, web, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, adblock

I'm trying to build a dyi adblock, that instead of just blocking ads, it first analyzes them based on their URL structure and their provided response from a fetch request
I'm using this as my starting point: https://github.com/AdrS/dyi-adblocker
I have a huge list of URLs and using webRequest.OnBeforeRequest to stop each request from that ad URL list and block them.
In the middle, I would like to first do a GET request to the stopped URL, get it's response, analyze everything and determine if it should be blocked or not.

I tried doing everything on a Google Chrome extension, based on thst github. But it seems to not be possible due to the listener not waiting for the fetch request (too async) + I'm getting "max stack size reached" errors. I searched for info on the internet and found out that it is somehow possible with a Mozilla Firefox extension, but couldn't find a solution.
Basically the steps should be:

1. Have a listener webRequest.OnBeforeRequest to stop requests from the urls in the list given.
2. fetch the URL's response
3. Analyze the URL's structure
4. Analyze the response
5. Calculate results
   6.1. If results are positive, allow the request to go through
   6.2. If results are negative, block the request

Speed is not an issue, it can even load for websites for minutes if needed, as this would be a small simple prototype.

Does anyone know a solution? Both Chrome and Firefox extension solutions work, as long as I can stall the webRequest.OnBeforeRequest (or anything else) for as long as I want until I do the needed analysis.

Any code examples and links to documentations are appreciated!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Sidenote: You may want to think about using `declarativeNetRequest` API as the `webRequest` API is "restricted to force-installed extensions in Manifest V3.". Otherwise provide some code examples to help us know where you're currently at.

Comment: Not possible in Chrome, you'll have to prepare the rules beforehand, also as mentioned webRequest can't use the blocking mode in normal MV3 extensions. In Firefox you can simply declare the listener with `async`, that's all.